# How can get last nth item of a query on PostgreSql

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

**Question:**

How I can get the last 750 records of a query in the `Database` level?

**Here is What I have tried:**

```py
# Get last 750 applications

apps = MyModel.active_objects.filter(
    **query_params
).order_by('-created_at').values_list('id', flat=True)[:750]
```

This query fetches all records that hit the `query_params` filter and after that return the last 750 records. So I want to do this work at the `database` level, like `mongoDb` aggregate queries. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: That *is* doing it at the database level. It does *not* fetch all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's not how Django works. The limit part is also done in database level.

[Django docs - Limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets):

> Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query.

To see what query is actually being run in the database you can simply print the query like this:

```
apps = MyModel.active_objects.filter(
           **query_params
       ).order_by('-created_at').values_list('id', flat=True)[:750]
print(apps.query)
```

The result will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "app_mymodel" WHERE <...> ORDER BY "app_mymodel"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 750
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.